# What happens if I pull more than 3 yellow tokens?

Tags: quacks

For set 4 of the yellow tokens in Quacks of Quedlingburg you get the value printed on the token (1/2/4) + N (the Nth token pulled).

[image]

What happens if I pull more than 3 yellow tokens? Do they keep getting N extra, 3 extra or no extra spaces?

I have the Dutch Megabox version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any yellow you draw after 3 are placed normally with no bonus.

From:
https://www.ultraboardgames.com/the-quacks-of-quedlinburg/ingredients.php

> For all further yellow chips drawn there is no more bonus.

Comment: Thanks!! Those descriptions on the website, are they from the rulebook of the base game?

Comment: I have the same description in German from the rulebook in front of me. It is from the base game.

Comment: I was unable to find that detail in the English rulebook. It does follow from a literal reading of the ingredient card, though; the card tells you what special things it does, and it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: I think "no more bonus" is very ambiguous. It could mean the bonus does not get any bigger - it still three. Or it could mean there is no more bonus applied to yellow tokens - you only get the token's natural value.

Comment: @JohnMcD I think "a 4th yellow gives 3 bonus placements would be as equally arbitrary/valid as "a 4th yellow gives 10 bonus placements". There's simply nothing in the wording/icons of the original ability to imply that any sort of bonus exists for a 4th yellow.

Comment: @Gendolkari  I don't think anyone is suggesting it would give 10 bonus placements. The original question is about three options: N bonus, 3 bonus, 0 bonus. I think the "no more" rules out N bonus as that is "more". A 3 bonus is not "more" as it's the same as the previous bonus - there is not more, just the same. Equally, 0 bonus is another way not to have "more" bonus because nobody is getting any bonus of any sort - not the same bonus, not less bonus, not more bonus. Honestly, I think your interpretation is right but I don't think the rulebook is absolutely clear here.

Comment: @JohnMcD I do agree that the wording of the FAQ by itself is not 100% clear and would be better if it left out the word "more". Combined with the most literal reading of the icons itself, I think it's more clear.